Equivalent of a() < b() < c() without chaining?
(Inspired by a question about an AEC to WebAssembly compiler and its answers, where I can imagine this might matter.)
The simple a() < b() and b() < c() isn't equivalent because b() might get called twice.
Using variables is better:
_a = a()
_b = b()
_a < _b and _b < c()

But even that isn't 100% equivalent. In particular, the value of a() is kept alive until after the second comparison, which could be problematic. I logged events with all three versions:
chained:
a() b() (3 4) del c() (3 3) del del 

simple_and:
a() b() (3 3) del del b() c() (3 3) del del 

variables:
a() b() (4 4) c() (4 3) del del del 

(del logs the "deletion" of objects returned by the functions, and the number pairs log the reference counts of the two compared objects during a comparison.)
Is there an equivalent way without chaining?
Testing script:
def chained():
    return a() < b() < c()

def simple_and():
    return a() < b() and b() < c()

def variables():
    _a = a()
    _b = b()
    return _a < _b and _b < c()


import sys

class X:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        print(end=f'({sys.getrefcount(self)} {sys.getrefcount(other)}) ')
        return True
    def __del__(self):
        print(end='del ')

def a(): print(end='a() '); return X()
def b(): print(end='b() '); return X()
def c(): print(end='c() '); return X()

for f in chained, simple_and, variables:
    print(f.__name__ + ':')
    f()
    print('\n')

Attempt This Online!

Every code can inspect the AST and behave differently, if you're mad scientist enough to write such code. ;) Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve with that? This question has a bit of "XY Problem" flavour to it, though I kind-of share the curiosity.

Finding an "equivalent" construction that satisfies Python's implementation internals doesn't seem very worthwhile. The variable-based approach should allow Python to delete _a after having evaluated _a < _b. That it doesn't do this is just a limitation of the Python implementation; a more sophisticated implementation would be free to do it.

@UlrichEckhardt Yes, if you allow code inspection, then of course there is no equivalent. That would make the question moot, so let's say equivalent other than that. No actual problem for me, I just saw that other question and its answers and I imagine for them it could matter. Especially the answers proposing to save a() in a variable and not deleting it before the second comparison. That could really have consequences.

@Luatic Actually, it probably cannot. Basing eligibility of Python objects for garbage collection on liveness instead of reachability could wreak havoc with finalizers and trigger countless use-after-free bugs.

Wouldn't this also change depending on the Python implementiation, i.e. whether it uses ref-counting or a garbage collector?

@UlrichEckhardt Yes, without ref-counting, I couldn't even log the ref counts. And a delayed garbage collection could even make the "the variable keeps a() alive until the end" argument somewhat moot, as it might be kept alive until the end anyway. But in CPython, and in that language/compiler that that inspiring question is about, it could matter.

We can replicate the original with lists and popping:
def popping():
    _a = [a()]
    _b = [b()]
    return _a.pop() < _b[0] and _b.pop() < c()

Simplified:
def popping_2():
    _b = [b()]
    return a() < _b[0] and _b.pop() < c()

And a version inspired by the bytecode shown by import dis; dis.dis('a < b < c'):
def popping_3():
    stack = [a(), b()]
    stack.reverse()
    stack[-2:-1] *= 2
    return stack.pop() < stack.pop() and stack.pop() < c()

Logs (Attempt This Online!):
chained:
a() b() (3 4) del c() (3 3) del del 

popping:
a() b() (3 4) del c() (3 3) del del 

popping_2:
b() a() (3 4) del c() (3 3) del del 

popping_3:
a() b() (3 4) del c() (3 3) del del 

Longer generalized case/solution:
def chained():
    return a() < b() < c() < d() < e()

def popping_4():
    stack = []
    def push(x):
        stack.append(x)
        return x
    pop = stack.pop
    return (
        a() < push(b()) and
        pop() < push(c()) and
        pop() < push(d()) and
        pop() < e()
    )

Log (Attempt This Online!):
chained:
a() b() (3 4) del c() (3 4) del d() (3 4) del e() (3 3) del del 

popping_4:
a() b() (3 4) del c() (3 4) del d() (3 4) del e() (3 3) del del 


You can use the walrus operator to save the value of b()
(a() < (temp_b := b())) and (temp_b < c())

I used the same structure in my answer to the question that inspired you.

Oops, I didn't scroll all the way down and missed your answer. But it's still not equivalent. Your ref counts during the second comparison are (4 3) instead of (3 3).

Using just variables, but having only b() be stored in a variable, also seems to work. Though the ref counts are different, but I don't see an issue with that.

@Luatic If you mean what I think you mean, then b() gets called before a(). That's worse.

@Luatic I'm not sure what you mean. I'm already only storing b() in a variable. If the chain were longer we'd need variables for all the intermediates.

@nocomment right, if the side effects of a, b and c interfere it's worse. If they are distinct and it's just about calling each one exactly once, it's fine.

Caveat: This doesn't generalize well to longer chains. If you have a() < (_b := b()) < (_c := c()) < d(), _b lives too long (for the rest of the expression, whereas it could be killed after evaluating _b < _c).

@Luatic Lifetimes of temporaries is an internal implementation issue, not part of the language semantics.

@Barmar that's true, but the OP is explicitly asking about these implementation details. Otherwise the approaches they present would be equivalent in terms of language semantics.

@Luatic That's not true if b() has side effects, then the difference is how many times those side effects occur.

@Luatic Actually it does generalize very well to longer chains if you use only one variable: (a() < (tmp := b())) and (tmp < (tmp := c())) and (tmp < (tmp := d())) and (tmp < e()). If you finish with and (tmp < ((tmp := None) or e())), then it even has the same a() b() (3 4) del c() (3 4) del d() (3 4) del e() (3 3) del del as you get from a() < b() < c() < d() < e().

@nocomment neat, didn't try that

If you place the functions in an iterable, such as [a, b, c], that allows "all" to pull only as much as it needs, thus replicating the short circuiting of the chained "and" operation, but you can control execution of the "call" operation so it only happens once.
from itertools import pairwise
from operator import call

def strictly_increasing(values) -> bool:
    """ test if values are strictly increasing """
    return all((x < y for x, y in pairwise(values)))

def function_values_increasing(functions) -> bool:
    """ test if function values are strictly increasing with no more than one call """
    return strictly_increasing(map(call, functions))\


def a():
    print ("a 1")
    return 1

def b():
    print("b 2")
    return 2

def c():
    print("c 3")
    return 3

print(function_values_increasing([a, b, c]))
print(function_values_increasing([c, b, a]))


a 1
b 2
c 3
True
c 3
b 2
False

The first test case is for increasing values, and shows that each of the functions are called exactly once.
The second test case is decreasing values, and shows that the last function is correctly not called because of the expected short-circuit.
As far as the exact lifetime of temporary objects within the function, that doesn't matter.
if you don't have 3.11
def call(f):
    """ from operator import call """
    return f()

if you don't have 3.10
def pairwise(iterable):
    # pairwise('ABCDEFG') → AB BC CD DE EF FG
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    a = next(iterator, None)
    for b in iterator:
        yield a, b
        a = b


In order to make it work for eval of the different code fragments, I think it would be ... fairly similar, except with eval instead of call. But the OP just had functions to be called, so I went with that.

"As far as the exact lifetime of temporary objects within the function, that doesn't matter" - It could matter. Depends on what the code is doing. My logging code is able to show it, and other code could use it, too. People do weird things sometimes.

I can replicate the side effects on different orders as well as support arbitrary length, but I admit, I can't replicate the lifetime. I was trusting that if the lifetime matters, it wouldn't have been deleted, unless you're specifically putting side effects inside the GC process -- which I admit I didn't deal with. I bet pairwise is holding a reference. Maybe I can refine that later.

Brutal solution: Use more variables, delete them when you no longer need them to force exactly the initialization / deletion and order (and count) of operations you want (attempt it online):
def variables():
    _a = a()
    _b = b()
    a_lt_b = _a < _b
    del _a
    return a_lt_b and _b < c()

Output: a() b() rc(a) = 4, rc(b) = 4 del a c() rc(b) = 4, rc(c) = 3 del c del b 
This also generalizes to longer chains:
def variables():
    _a = a()
    _b = b()
    a_lt_b = _a < _b
    if not a_lt_b:
        return a_lt_b # short-circuiting
    del _a
    _c = c()
    b_lt_c = _b < _c
    if not b_lt_c:
        return b_lt_c
    del _b
    _d = d()
    c_lt_d = _c < _d
    del _c
    del _d
    return c_lt_d

By spelling out exactly what you want to happen and when, you get the desired order of

Evaluation of a(), b(), c() and d(), each at most once (short circuiting);
Deletion of each as soon as the comparisons involving it have been computed, from left to right;
Deletion of c() before d(), as a() < b() < c() < d() does.


"Caveat": Reference counts are not equal, but unless you can construct a case where this leads to a different order of initialization, deletion or evaluation, I would consider this an implementation detail and not a problem of semantical equivalence. I don't think that the increased reference counts will be a problem in practice, because they should coincide precisely with the references taken in the expressions.

Well, I'd say it's highly unlikely that a program is affected by the differing reference counts, but it's possible. And since this was inspired by someone writing a compiler for arbitrary code written by others, I'd want to replicate the ref counts exactly. Who knows what code such other people will write...

@nocomment if you're writing a compiler, you have full control of this. You don't need to work around Python's particular implementation details. Only if you're writing a transpiler targeting Python you would have to care about this, otherwise you could create these "variables" as proper temporaries. And as said, I think this is most likely already fine as-is, because nothing weird can happen: The lifetime of the variable always ends immediately after the expression(s) involving it have been computed. How could a user possibly get any breakage out of this?

Not sure about that. The inspiring question is about "AEC to WebAssembly", and I know neither of them.

@nocomment fixed. I'm used to languages forcing comparison operators to produce bools (e.g. Lua).

Ah, is that where you name comes from? You're a Lua lunatic?

@nocomment indeed :)
